# Cannot get element by attribute value with XDocument

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-xml

I've got `customUIXml` object of type `XDocument` and it has the following XML as value:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab id="t1" label="Shalala">
        <!-- stuff -->
      </tab>
      <tab id="tab_dev" label="SomeOtherTab">
        <!-- stuff -->
      </tab>
      <tab id="t108" label="MyTab">
        <!-- stuff -->
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

and I want to get the `tab` node with label value "MyTab". This is the code I use:

```
Dim xtab As XElement = Nothing
Dim nodes = From nodeToTake In customUIXml.Descendants().Elements("tab") _
            Where nodeToTake.Attribute("label").Value = "MyTab"
            Select nodeToTake

For Each tab As XElement In nodes
    xtab = tab
Next
```

But I get no results and I can't seem to find what am I doing wrong...

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use XML literals, so your code would be as easy as:

```
Dim xtab = customUIXml.<ribbon>.<tabs>.<tab>.First(Function(tab) tab.@label = "MyTab")
```

Also, your code seems to work, so your problem seems to be elsewhere.

```
Dim customUIXml = <customUI>
<ribbon>
    <tabs>
    <tab id="t1" label="Shalala">
        <!-- stuff -->
    </tab>
    <tab id="tab_dev" label="SomeOtherTab">
        <!-- stuff -->
    </tab>
    <tab id="t108" label="MyTab">
        <!-- stuff -->
    </tab>
    </tabs>
</ribbon>
</customUI>

Dim xtab As XElement = Nothing
Dim nodes = From nodeToTake In customUIXml.Descendants().Elements("tab") _
            Where nodeToTake.Attribute("label").Value = "MyTab"
            Select nodeToTake

For Each tab As XElement In nodes
    xtab = tab
Next

Console.WriteLine(xtab)
```

displays

```
<tab id="t108" label="MyTab">
  <!-- stuff -->
</tab>
```

just fine.

---

If your actual XML contains a namespace, you have to take that into account:

```
...
Dim df As XNamespace = customUIXml.Name.Namespace

Dim xtab As XElement = Nothing
Dim nodes = From nodeToTake In customUIXml.Descendants().Elements(df + "tab") _
            ...
```

Comment: using the literals gives me exception `Sequence contains no matching element`... And I check the XML and the node is there.... Also, do you think the problem with using linq-to-xml might be connected with the namespace?

Comment: @Syspect If your XML has a namespace, you have to take that into account. As my answer shows, the xml you postet in your question works just fine with your code. So if your actual XML is different (by e.g. using a namespace), you should update your question to include that.

Comment: @Syspect See my update on how to include the namespace into your query

Comment: I updated the XML in my post. But trying to do `Dim df As XNamespace = customUIXml.Name.Namespace` says that `Name` is not a member of `System.Xml.Linq.XDocument`, so I can't assign the namespace.

Comment: @Syspect In my answer I use the XML of your question, which is an `XElement`. It seems in your real code you use an `XDocument`, so you have to use `Dim df As XNamespace = customUIXml.Root.Name.Namespace` instead of `Dim df As XNamespace = customUIXml.Name.Namespace`.

Comment: Still nothing... The query just returns an empty collection.

Comment: @Syspect Then the XML you use does not match the XML you postet in your question

Answer (score 0):

```
string xml = "<customUI xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui' onLoad='Ribbon_Load'><ribbon><tabs><tab id='t1' label='Shalala'><!-- stuff --></tab><tab id='tab_dev' label='SomeOtherTab'><!-- stuff --></tab><tab id='t108' label='MyTab'><!-- stuff --></tab></tabs></ribbon></customUI>";

var xelement = XElement.Parse(xml);
var list = xelement.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "tab" && x.Attribute("label") != null).ToList();
list.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Attribute("label").Value));
```

you can access localName to check the elment tag value , 
Checked with LinqPad and it works expectedly hope that helps..

:)

Edit : Vb code from Telerik convert :

```
Dim xml As String = "<customUI xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui' onLoad='Ribbon_Load'><ribbon><tabs><tab id='t1' label='Shalala'><!-- stuff --></tab><tab id='tab_dev' label='SomeOtherTab'><!-- stuff --></tab><tab id='t108' label='MyTab'><!-- stuff --></tab></tabs></ribbon></customUI>"

Dim xelement__1 = XElement.Parse(xml)
Dim list = xelement__1.Descendants().Where(Function(x) x.Name.LocalName = "tab" AndAlso x.Attribute("label") IsNot Nothing).ToList()
list.ForEach(Function(x) Console.WriteLine(x.Attribute("label").Value))
```